# Walls not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I exported some mesh in fbx format and imported in Unity. As you can see in the screenshoots, the walls are not shown to the camera. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be wrong normals.
Fly around in the scene view and check if the room is visible from the outside. If so, invert the normals with a 3D modeling programm.
Or change the shader to show both sides (disable Backface culling)

Comment: Thanks aalmigthy, it was the wrong normals. I forgot to check that. I change them in my 3d modeling program.

Comment: Glad to help :-) Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.